# Prevent local caching of responses in HTTP streaming

Tags: php, javascript, apache, caching, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to stream data read from a file to chrome client. I am able to stream data successfully but my responses are getting cached and I want to prevent that from happening. This situation is there because my flat file contains data entries which are independent of each other and i want to treat them likewise. For example, my file contains :

`{idle_time:94125387364,system_time:98954710321,user_time:3683963615}
{idle_time:94125387789,system_time:98954710456,user_time:3683963845}
{idle_time:94125387876,system_time:98954710678,user_time:3683963986}`

so instead of getting 
{idle_time:94125387876,system_time:98954710678,user_time:3683963986}
(THIRD ENTRY) 
as xmlhttprequest.responsetext, I receive

```
{idle_time:94125387364,system_time:98954710321,user_time:3683963615} <br/>
{idle_time:94125387789,system_time:98954710456,user_time:3683963845} <br/>
{idle_time:94125387876,system_time:98954710678,user_time:3683963986}
```

NOTE : I am not worried about breakline tags and blankspace.

My PHP script looks like this,
test.php

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0); 
$filename = 'D:\Smoke_Test\data.txt';

function flush2 (){
echo(str_repeat(' ',256));
// check that buffer is actually set before flushing
if (ob_get_length()){            
    @ob_flush();
    @flush();
    @ob_end_flush();
}    
@ob_start();
}

$file_last_modified_time = 0;

while(true) 
{
$modified_time = filemtime($filename);
$processor_info = "";
if ($file_last_modified_time < $modified_time)  
{
    header("Expires: Sun, 20 Jan 1985 00:00:00 GMT"); // date in the past
    header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
    header("Pragma: no-cache");
    $file_last_modified_time = $modified_time;
    $handle = fopen($filename,"r");
    $processor_info = fgets ($handle);
    fclose ($handle);
    @ob_clean();
    echo $processor_info."<br/>";
    //flush2();
}
flush2();
sleep(1);
clearstatcache(true, $filename);
}

?>
```

and my html page looks like this:
Home.htm

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-     transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript" language = "javascript">
function read_file ()
{
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
        xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 || xmlhttp.readyState==3 ) //&& xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
            handle_data (xmlhttp.responseText);
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("POST","test.php",true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}

function handle_data (input)
{
    document.getElementById("txtResponse").innerHTML=input;
}
</script>

</head>
<body>
<p>
<input type="button" id="dtnSendRequest" value="Send Request" onclick="read_file()"/>
</p>
<p>
response : <span id="txtResponse"></span>
<!-- <input type="text" id="txtResponse" width="500"/> -->
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant avoid whats happening with responseText. Its the nature of Http Streaming (not local or any caching) makes that happen. I found a very good article which states my situation as well as the solution.

The article is http://ajaxpatterns.org/archive/HTTP_Streaming.php

Following paragraph contains my situation as well as solution for it.

"The responseText property of XMLHttpRequest always contains the content that's been flushed out of the server, even when the connection's still open. So the browser can run a periodic check, e.g. to see if its length has changed. One problem, though, is that, once flushed, the service can't undo anything its output. For example, the responseText string arising from a timer service might look like this: "12:00:00 12:01:05 12:01:10", whereas it would ideally be just "12:00:00", then just "12:01:05", then just "12:01:10". The solution is to parse the response string and only look at the last value. To be more precise, the last complete value, since it's possible the text ends with a partial result. An example of this technique works in this way. To ease parsing, the service outputs each message delimited by a special token, "@END@" (an XML tag would be an alternative approach). Then, a regular expression can be run to grab the latest message, which must be followed by that token to ensure it's complete"

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to the top of your php file

```
header("Expires: Sun, 20 Jan 1985 00:00:00 GMT"); // date in the past
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Comment: I changed the php code but problem is still there. You can see changed code in question.

Comment: what do the headers in your browser say when requesting the page?

Comment: Request Header:POST /Dashboard/test.php HTTP/1.1

Host: localhost:8080

Connection: keep-alive

Content-Length: 0

Origin: http://localhost:8080

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.162 Safari/535.19

Accept: */*

Referer: http://localhost:8080/Dashboard/Home.htm

Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8

Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

Comment: Response Header:                                                Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Type:text/html
Date:Sun, 15 Apr 2012 15:30:29 GMT
Expires:Sun, 20 Jan 1985 00:00:00 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=5, max=100
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Apache/2.2.21 (Win64) PHP/5.3.10
Transfer-Encoding:chunked
X-Powered-By:PHP/5.3.10

Answer (score 0):

Use this to force no-cache:

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

Make sure you call this before sending any output.

Comment: I changed the php code but problem is still there. You can see changed code in question

Comment: Got Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\wamp\www\Dashboard\test.php:14)